# Calculating MAX and MIN Latitude and Longitude with distance from Location - Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, macos, maps

I need to compute MAX and MIN Latitude and Longitude values from a location with certain distance.

I have thousands of locations stored in CoreData, and I want to show only the ones within 5km from users location.

How can I approach this problem?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's a possible solution:

1. macros to convert Degrees to Radians

   ```
   #define deg2rad(degrees) ((degrees) / 180.0 M_PI)
   ```
2. macros to hold my searching distance

   ```
   #define searchDistance 5.00 //float value in KM
   ```
3. set the minimum and maximum Latitude, Longitude values

   ```
   float minLat = userLocation.coordinate.latitude - (searchDistance / 69);
   float maxLat = userLocation.coordinate.latitude + (searchDistance / 69);
   float minLon = userLocation.coordinate.latitude - searchDistance / fabs(cos(deg2rad(userLocation.coordinate.latitude))*69);
   float maxLon = userLocation.coordinate.longitude + searchDistance / fabs(cos(deg2rad(userLocation.coordinate.latitude))*69);
   ```
4. create predicate as follows

   ```
   NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"latitude <= %f AND latitude >= %f AND longitude <= %f AND longitude >= %f", maxLat, minLat, maxLon, minLon];
   ```

This will create a square around `userLocation` and check if a given location falls into its coordinates.

> Update: Swift 2.* implementation

First create a function to compute degrees to radians

```
func deg2rad(degrees:Double) -> Double{
    return degrees * M_PI / 180
}
```

Compute and create minimum and maximum `Latitude` and `Longitude` values

```
let searchDistance:Double =  5.00 //float value in KM    

let minLat = userLocation.coordinate.latitude - (searchDistance / 69)
let maxLat = userLocation.coordinate.latitude + (searchDistance / 69)

let minLon = userLocation.coordinate.longitude - searchDistance / fabs(cos(deg2rad(userLocation.coordinate.latitude))*69)
let maxLon = userLocation.coordinate.longitude + searchDistance / fabs(cos(deg2rad(userLocation.coordinate.latitude))*69)
```

Last create `NSPredicate` to query `CoreData` for locations. In my case I am querying for values `latitude` and `longitude` but you should change this to match your `CoreData` object

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "latitude <= \(maxLat) AND latitude >= \(minLat) AND longitude <= \(maxLon) AND longitude >= \(minLon)")
```

Comment: See the comments above, this is probably an excellent solution for your use case unless it really matters that you only get results that are less than "exactly" 5km.

Comment: Thank you for you comment. I simply needed location within approximate distance. I am not relying on exact distance at all, but wanted to filter big database to only few dozens without selecting the entire database.

Comment: I think there is a typo, e.g. `float minLon = userLocation.coordinate.latitude...` should be `float minLon = userLocation.coordinate.longitude...`, or?

Comment: This won't work when the 5km radius is crossing the 180th meridian.

Comment: I know. I never said it is as accurate as `distanceFromLocation()` the only purpose of this calculation is to build a query and only loop through the returned result instead of selecting the entire database and check each entry, which could be huge overhead if you have thousands of records like in my case.

Comment: @Pancho It's easy to catch that case though and build a two part query. Basically someone crossing the 180th meridian will see everything on the other side of the dateline vanish and things on the other side suddenly pop in.

Answer (score 0):

Use the CoreLocation method `distanceFromLocation:` which returns the distance (in meters) between two points as such:

```
CLLocation* location = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:lat longitude:lon];
if([userLocation distanceFromLocation:location) < searchDistance)
    // do something with close point
```

A suitable predicate can be constructed as:

```
NSPredicate* predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:(BOOL (^)(NSDictionary* target, NSDictionary *bindings)) {
    CLLocation* location = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:[target[@"lat"] doubleValue] longitude:[target[@"lon"] doubleValue]];
    return [userLocation distanceFromLocation:location] < searchDistance;
}];
```

This has the advantage that it returns the items actually within range, as opposed to the items in a square approximating the range.  It's also (probably, we don't know the details) using a more accurate approximation of the range itself.  It has the disadvantage that the predicate requires loading every object since it can't be expressed as an sqlite query.

Comment: Would this be more efficient than only selecting lat and lon between minimum and maximum values?

Comment: No, the math used by distanceFromLocation is more complex (by an order of magnitude) than an optimized version of Panayot's math.  If you're using an NSPredicate to fetch data from CoreData, Panayot's method has the added advantage that the predicate will generate an sqlite query so not all items will be loaded.

Comment: My order of magnitude estimate is based on the belief that distanceFromLocation uses haversine great circle approximation.  Panayot's method has the added disadvantage that the assumption that long lines are parallel makes for degrading results with larger radiuses (should be fine for 5 km assuming you're not sitting on or very close to the pole)  To get an answer that has both optimal performance and highest accuracy, use a combination of the two.  Use Panayot's for a rough filter and then apply distanceFromLocation filtering.