# CoreData: Fetching entities with special condition

Tags: ios, core-data, nspredicate

In my database, I have a entity called "Address", there are 140k rows of Addresses. Each address has attributes "lat" and "lng", indicating the latitude and longitude of the address.

Provided that I have acquired user location from location service, how could I traversing all addresses and find the address nearest to the user location?

I already have code to construct Haversine distance if I can get latitude and longitude of an address, but my problem is I don't know how to do it in predicate.

My current code for getting nearest Addreses from an array:

```
// user location acquired from location service
CLLocationCoordinate2D currentLocationCoordinate = location.coordinate;
float dist = FLT_MAX;
int nearestAddressIndex = -1;
for(int i = 0; i < [addresses count]; ++i) {
    NSDictionary *address = addresses[i];
    Haversine *haverObject = [[Haversine alloc] initWithLat1:currentLocationCoordinate.latitude
                                                        lon1:currentLocationCoordinate.longitude
                                                        lat2:[address[@"lat"] floatValue]
                                                        lon2:[address[@"lng"] floatValue]];
    if ([haverObject toMeters] < dist ) {
        dist = [haverObject toMeters];
        nearestAddressIndex = i;
    }
}
```

Is there a way I could construct a predicate? Or must I fetching all addresses in an array and traversing the array?

I am a bit reluctant to do the latter, as I worry it might cause the app to terminate due to memory pressure.

**Also another similar question that occur somewhere else in my app:**

In this second case, I need to get all the Address that falls within a certain radius around the user location. Below is my code for array:

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D currentLocationCoordinate = location.coordinate;
CGFloat threshold = 500.0f;
NSMutableArray *nearbyStation = [NSMutableArray array];

for (NSDictionary *station in [DataHelper sharedInstance].stations)
{
    CGFloat lat = [station[@"lat"] floatValue];
    CGFloat lng = [station[@"lng"] floatValue];

    Haversine *haverObject = [[Haversine alloc] initWithLat1:currentLocationCoordinate.latitude
                                                        lon1:currentLocationCoordinate.longitude
                                                        lat2:lat
                                                        lon2:lng];
    if ([haverObject toMeters] <= threshold)
    {
        [nearbyStation addObject:station];
    }
}
```

I have the above code for my datas that are stored in array. But how could I do the same thing for my "Address" which is stored in core data?

Comment: Take a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23015484/calculating-max-and-min-latitude-and-longitude-with-distance-from-location-obj/23017958#23017958

Answer (score 0):

It's better if you traverse only one value of your Entity. You could try adapting something like this:

```
NSEntityDescription *description = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Address"
                                               inManagedObjectContext:[yourContext managedObjectContext]];
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[request setEntity:description];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"exampleLatitute < dist"];
[request setPredicate:predicate];
NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *array = [[yourContext managedObjectContext] executeFetchRequest:request
                                                                   error:&error];
```

Answer (score 0):

Your predicate needs to search for items within a range of the lat lng of the user location.

[Check this link](http://www.objc.io/issue-4/core-data-fetch-requests.html) for an example of how to construct the predicate.  Once you have all the items that are close you can then sort them to determine the distance.  The link also provide an example of how you might do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a predicate to find a subset of the Addresses
that are within a given range, that is nearby the user location.
For example: `(minLat < lat < maxLat) AND (minLon < lon < maxLon)`.
NSPredicate cannot handle more complex equations.

```
predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"lng > %@ AND lng < %@ AND lat > %@ AND lat < %@", minLong, maxLong, minLat, maxLat];

[request setPredicate:predicate];
NSError *error;
NSArray *matchingData = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
```