# Objects from coredata inside a radius from current locations based on objects his latitude and longitude

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nspredicate, latitude-longitude, nsfetchrequest

I want to get all the objects that are inside a radius of 5km from my certain location. At the moment I have the following:

```
_searchDistance = 2.50;

    AppDelegate *appDelegate = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;


    float minLat = appDelegate.latitude - (_searchDistance / 69);
    float maxLat = appDelegate.latitude + (_searchDistance / 69);
    float minLon = appDelegate.longitude - _searchDistance / fabs(cos(appDelegate.longitude / 180.0 * M_PI)*69);
    float maxLon = appDelegate.longitude + _searchDistance / fabs(cos(appDelegate.longitude / 180.0 * M_PI)*69);

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription
                                   entityForName:@"Relation" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"rel_latitude <= %f AND rel_latitude >= %f AND rel_longitude <= %f AND rel_longitude >= %f", maxLat, minLat, maxLon, minLon];
    [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];
    NSSortDescriptor *sort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]
                              initWithKey:@"rel_name" ascending:YES selector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)];
    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:sort,nil]];

    NSArray *matches = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil];
```

This piece of code is based on the following [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23015484/calculating-max-and-min-latitude-and-longitude-with-distance-from-location-obj)

But this creates a square arround the current location. And this results in returning the wrong values. So can somebody please help me with this ?

Comment: What do you mean by wrong values? - And of course you get a "square" with your predicate. You *cannot* fetch objects within a given distance if only lat/lon are stored in the entity because both predicate and sort descriptor can only use *persistent* attributes. - As I tried to explain in the answer to a previous question, you have either to store the distance as a persistent attribute, or filter the fetched objects in memory (where you *can* use any Objective-C based filter).

Comment: @MartinR I did understand your answer. But my question is now can we turn the square into a circle? Doesn't their exist some mathematical formula ?

Comment: `xmin <= x <= xmax AND ymin <= y <= ymax` is a square, and `(x-x0)^2 + (y-y0)^2 <= r^2` is a circle. The first is allowed in a Core Data fetch request, but the second is not. (That is a Core Data restriction, not an SQL restriction). I do not see a solution other than fetching the objects of an enclosing square first and then filter in memory again.

Answer (score 0):

As Martin suggests, just continue cutting down the result.

```
NSMutableArray *filtered = [NSMutableArray array];
for (Relation *object in matches) {
  float lonDelta = object.rel_longitude.floatValue -centerLon;
  float latDelta = object.rel_latitude.floatValue - centerLat;
  if (radius*radius <= lonDelta*lonDelta + latDelta*latDelta) {
     [filtered addObject:object];
  }
}
```

Please note that this is a (usually sufficient) approximation supposing that the earth is a flat plane.

Comment: CLLocation has a distanceFromLocation: method to compute the distance of two points on the earth more precisely.

Comment: Right, I forgot about that one.